# Instantiate prisma only once

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I am currently using prisma 2.20.1 on a project running postgres.

On their doc they say to import PrismaClient and instantiate it throughout the application.

However, coming from other use cases, where you connect to the db only once, feels weird on every route (different file and directory as my project structure is set to), to instantiate, and (connect to the db again?).

My point is, is there a way to centralize the database connection in one file, and use its instance throughout the application? Would it be safe to do that? Any consequences?

My idea is something like:

```js
// database.ts
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.db = new PrismaClient();
    }
}

const database = new Database();

export default new Database();
```

Then across the routes files

```js
// specificRouteFile.ts
import db from 'database';

// run queries...
db.SomeTable.create({})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and initialize Prisma in a file and then import it across the different files.

```js
//lib/prisma.js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default prisma;
```

Then in a different file for example, just do

```js
import prisma from "./lib/prisma"

const posts = prisma.posts.findMany({})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. In this approach, would it be connecting and disconnecting to the db on every import?

Comment: nope, as imports are normally cached

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by [@Mahmoud Abdelwahab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66920090/6904888) I created a TypeScript (instantiate) version:

```js
// lib/prisma.ts
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

interface CustomNodeJsGlobal {
  prisma: PrismaClient;
}

declare const global: CustomNodeJsGlobal;

const prisma = global.prisma || new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') global.prisma = prisma;

export default prisma;
```

After creating this file, you can now import this `PrismaClient` instance anywhere. You can get in-depth information about instance PrismaClient [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/support/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices).

```
import prisma from '../lib/prisma';
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case is to instantiate a single instance PrismaClient and save it on the [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) object. Then we keep a check to only instantiate PrismaClient if it's not on the globalThis object otherwise use the same instance again if already present to prevent instantiating extra PrismaClient instances.

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const globalForPrisma = globalThis as unknown as {
  prisma: PrismaClient | undefined
}

export const prisma = globalForPrisma.prisma ?? new PrismaClient()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalForPrisma.prisma = prisma
```